# Combine Website in git Repository with TFS Build

Tags: git, tfs, web-deployment, tfsbuild, msdeploy

We have a backend C# Solution which provides web services. And a frontend website which accesses the backend.

Both of them should be deployed automatically on one server for testing.

Deploying the backend is no problem - I can use the TFS Build for building the projects and deploy them to the server.

But how can I deploy the frontend website? It is not integrated in any Solution or Project in Visual Studio. Because it is just simple HTML, JavaScript etc. and doesn't contain any ASP code or something.
The only place, where I can find the website files, is at the Build Server in the local src folder.

So the only options I see is one of the following:
1. Access the src folder on the Build Server via Batch-File. Or
2. Create a new project that contains all the website Files

Both of them do not look as a proper solution.
The first one because I think its bad practice to pick my own files out from the buildserver. The second because I would have to add every file manually to this project.

Any better ideas or experience?

Comment: what tech is the front end written in, is it asp.net or something else?

Comment: The front end is written just with HTML, CSS, jQuery, javascript.